# JS file not pulling model.findByPk() using "/:id"?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to pull items from my database using each item's `id`, but am receiving an empty object when running it through Insomnia.  For example, in the code below, I would like to pull a category by ID, but also include any associated Products.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?  Thank you in advance!

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const oneCategory = await Category.findByPk({
      include: [{ model: Product }]
    });
    // console.log(oneCategory);
    if (!oneCategory) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'No category found with that id!' });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).json(oneCategory);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

[image: Empty Object in Insomnia]

[image: Category Table in DB]

Answer (score 0):

When calling the **findByPk** method, you need to pass the key you are looking for. In this particular case, the code should look like this:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const oneCategory = await Category.findByPk(req.params.id, {
      include: [{ model: Product }]
    });

    if (!oneCategory) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'No category found with that id!' });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).json(oneCategory);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

So just grab the id from the URL with **req.params.id** and pass it to **findByPk**. However, it could be a good idea to check so that the id is in fact an integer before doing so :)